# MVC Auto run on Deployment

Tags: c#, windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

I've found a lot of resources for MVC on Linux and deploying from Visual Studio to an EC2 Instance, but nothing that follows our CI architecture

My stack:
 -> c#.NET MVC 
 -> Commit to Bitbucket
 -> AWS EC2 Bamboo server (builds repo and push to s3)
 -> Then deploys to EC2 Testing Instance.
 -> From there I can manually paste the "application url" in to a browser and the app runs.

My question is... how do I get the deployed application to run automatically?

- In the appspec.yml? There are very few scripts for a .NET(windows) related appspec.yml file.
- Or, can I run an additional task and preform this step? (This would be my preferred method)

Could I also please get an example of the **Windows based** script/code as well.

***Note:** To get the app running I on my Testing Instance, I followed: [see steps 4.1 - 5.4](https://bytescout.com/blog/2016/06/blog201606blog201605setting-webserver-asp-net-mvc-application-aws-ec2-html-html.html)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Guys - please format your question "sharply" - this is next question where I don't know what you are talking about.

Your question: "application running automatically"?  Nothing gets run automatically. It can be run by some tool but not automatically. And what is your tool

Comment: So, it sounds like you're looking for a script to setup IIS on your testing instance?

Comment: @Piotr - My apologies.

I want a know if I should use a script(called from appspec) or a bamboo task(script or other) that loads the MVC web app after the app has been deployed. *IIS is setup on Testing EC2.

If the recommended solution is a script called from appspec; what would an example of this script be as there are very few Windows related examples.

If a bamboo task. Which task is best suited for this?

Comment: I'm starting with a small test app. But, my end goal is to run a multi-service application on the Testing EC2 from my bamboo server. Once all the services are up and running. I then need to run selenium tests against it.

Answer (score 0):

CodeDeploy has a sample app here for Windows, you might find it helpful: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-codedeploy-samples/tree/master/applications/SampleApp_Windows

Basically Linux or Windows app should not have much difference in terms of CodeDeploy aspect. CodeDeploy just help you to run scripts that are defined by you.